# How to I prevent exec from keeping the script running?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, exec

I'm using `exec` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee /tmp/mylog.log) 2>&1
bash -c 'sleep 12312' &
```

I want the output of the commands to be in a log file, and then I want to start a long running script, and completely detach it, without doing anything to its output.

But I've noticed that running a script with exec to redirect output to a file makes it continue running with the long-running script. For example, save the above script to a file `/tmp/start.sh`, run it, `ps aux` will show that `/bin/bash /tmp/start.sh` is still running!

If I remove the exec line, however, it's working as expected.

So how do I "detach" exec stdout redirection and have the script die once it's over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash process that keeps running is the parent of `tee`, not the original script. You can see that by adding traces that display the process IDs:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo original=$$
exec > >(echo substitution=$BASHPID; tee /tmp/mylog.log) 2>&1
bash -c 'echo sleeper=$$; sleep 12312' &
```

This makes an additional bash process appear, the parent of `sleep`. To get rid of these bash processes, use `exec` throughout:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo original=$$
exec > >(echo substitution=$BASHPID; exec tee /tmp/mylog.log) 2>&1
bash -c 'echo sleeper=$$; exec sleep 12312' &
```

I tested this answer on bash 4.3. Future versions of bash may become smarter about not tail calls (like ksh).